# Refactoring a class component to a Functional component with contexts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to refactor some code from classes to functional components so that it is consistent with the rest of my app. The classes are updating state and in the app they will need to update a context called cardContext.js. The first thing I need to do is re-write the classes into functional components so that update a context rather than internal state.

The bulk of my site works through functional components with hooks and I am using context.

Each context has 3 files;

- ExampleState.js
- exampleContext.js
- exampleReducer.js

The code for the app so far is here https://codesandbox.io/s/infshot-978on?fontsize=14) (the preview does not work as I don't think codesandbox can do full stack apps , but you can see the relavant code via client> src> components>card and client> src> components>context>card.

I am trying to integrate some components that are coded as classes into my app to work in the same way so that I can integrate it. First I need to refactor these so that they are functional components and use context in the same form as the rest of my app. The new components are useing a framework called React Beautiful DND and I created them using tutorials which created class components.

I am stuck figuring out how to refactor them.

The first file I am trying to refactor is below

```
// files in context/dnd editor are placeholders
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '@atlaskit/css-reset';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import '../../index.css'

import styled from 'styled-components';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import initialData from './initialData';
import Column from './column';


const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

export default class dndEditor extends React.Component {
  state = initialData;

  onDragEnd = result => {
    document.body.style.color = 'inherit';
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    const start = this.state.columns[source.droppableId];
    const finish = this.state.columns[destination.droppableId];

    if (start === finish) {
      const newTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds);
      newTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
      newTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);

      const newColumn = {
        ...start,
        taskIds: newTaskIds
      };
      const newState = {
        ...this.state,
        columns: {
          ...this.state.columns,
          [newColumn.id]: newColumn
        }
      };
      this.setState(newState);
      return;
    }
    //Start and finnish columns are different
    const startTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds);
    startTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
    const newStart = {
      ...start,
      taskIds: startTaskIds
    };

    const finishTaskIds = Array.from(finish.taskIds);
    finishTaskIds.splice(source.index, 0, draggableId);
    const newFinish = {
      ...finish,
      taskIds: finishTaskIds
    };

    const newState = {
      ...this.state,
      columns: {
        ...this.state.columns,
        [newStart.id]: newStart,
        [newFinish.id]: newFinish
      }
    };
    this.setState(newState);
    return;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
          {this.state.columnOrder.map(columnId => {
            const column = this.state.columns[columnId];
            const tasks = column.taskIds.map(
              taskId => this.state.tasks[taskId]
            );

            return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;
          })}
        </DragDropContext>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the initialData.js file  (initial state) is below

```
const InitialData = {
  tasks: {
    'task-1': {
      id: 'task-1',
      content: 'Take out the trash and another thing also'
    },
    'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'another link' },
    'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'clear desk' },
    'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'do pushups' }
  },
  columns: {
    'column-1': {
      id: 'column-1',
      title: 'FACTS',
      taskIds: ['task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']
    },
    'column-2': {
      id: 'column-2',
      title: 'PROS',
      taskIds: ['task-1']
    },
    'column-3': {
      id: 'column-3',
      title: 'CONS',
      taskIds: []
    }
  },
  columnOrder: ['column-1', 'column-2', 'column-3']
};
export default InitialData;
```

(all files I would like to refactor are in the functional codesandbox below)
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-trello-example-ohxsi?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what exact is challenging. refactoring `setState` + `this.state` into `useState` should work. This component is providing context, not consuming. So everything related to context stays as it's now.

```
export default function DndEditor() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialData);

  onDragEnd = result => {
    document.body.style.color = 'inherit';
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    const start = state.columns[source.droppableId];
    const finish = state.columns[destination.droppableId];

    if (start === finish) {
      const newTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds);
      newTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
      newTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);

      const newColumn = {
        ...start,
        taskIds: newTaskIds
      };
      const newState = {
        ...this.state,
        columns: {
          ...state.columns,
          [newColumn.id]: newColumn
        }
      };
      setState(newState);
      return;
    }
    //Start and finnish columns are different
    const startTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds);
    startTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
    const newStart = {
      ...start,
      taskIds: startTaskIds
    };

    const finishTaskIds = Array.from(finish.taskIds);
    finishTaskIds.splice(source.index, 0, draggableId);
    const newFinish = {
      ...finish,
      taskIds: finishTaskIds
    };

    const newState = {
      ...state,
      columns: {
        ...state.columns,
        [newStart.id]: newStart,
        [newFinish.id]: newFinish
      }
    };
    setState(newState);
    return;
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        {state.columnOrder.map(columnId => {
          const column = state.columns[columnId];
          const tasks = column.taskIds.map(
            taskId => state.tasks[taskId]
          );
           return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;
        })}
      </DragDropContext>
     </Container>
  );
}
```

Further you may want to split `state` into independent

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(initialData.columns);
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(initialData.tasks);
```

for better readability, but for first try `[state, setState]` would be simplest way to refactor.